# How do we test a `Range` type in Elixir

Tags: types, elixir

How do we test for a `Range` type? What would be the equivalent of `is_range`?

```
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.1] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1]

Interactive Elixir (1.7.3) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> a = 1..10
1..10
iex(2)> is_list a
false
iex(3)> i a
Term
  1..10
Data type
  Range
Description
  This is a struct. Structs are maps with a __struct__ key.
Reference modules
  Range, Map
Implemented protocols
  IEx.Info, Enumerable, Inspect
iex(4)>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you need this function in the first place? [`Range`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Range.html) is a struct. We have pattern matching everywhere you might need it. Just pattern match to `%Range{}` and you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no equivalent in Kernel, but you can create it by yourself:

```
def is_range(%Range{}), do: true
def is_range(_), do: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers have mentioned, `Range` is a struct and you can pattern match on it. **This is how you would test it in `ExUnit`:**

```
assert %Range{} = 1..5
```

If you want to test the start/end values, you can do this:

```
assert %Range{end: 20} = 10..20
```

Comment: Which is a pattern match btw :)